# Eliminar Materia

Tags: laravel, relaciones

Cree un método para agregar una materia a un alumno y obtener su promedio, mediante lo sig:

```
    public function agregarMateria(Request $request, $id)
{
    $alumno_add = Alumno::find($id);
    $materias = $request->get("materia_id");

    foreach ($materias as $materia) {

        $aId = $materia["id"];
        $aCalificacion = $materia["calificacion"];
        $mat = Materia::find($aId);
        $alumno_add->materias()->attach([$mat->id => ["calificacion" => $aCalificacion]]);
        
    }

     
    $alumno_add->load('materias');
    $promedio_result = $alumno_add->materias->avg("pivot.calificacion");
    $alumno_add->promedio = $promedio_result;

    $alumno_add->save();

    return $alumno_add;


}
```

Después intente hacer una funcion, para eliminar una materia del alumno y actualizar su promedio, pero me falla en postman, la funcio es la sig.

```
 public function eliminarMateria(Request $request, $id)
{
    $alumnoFind = Alumno::find($id)->load('materias'); 

    $materias = $request->get("materia_id");
    $suma = $alumnoFind->materias->whereIn('id', $materias)->avg("pivot.calificacion");
    $alumnoFind->materias()->detach($materias);

    $alumnoFind->save();

    return $alumnoFind;


}
```

al parecer me borra todas las materias y no me actualiza el promedio.

Comment: Eliminar materia no deberia recibir tambien la materia a eliminar?

Comment: por lo que veo no estas guardando el promedio y la otra es que te llega en $materias? si elimina varios es o que llega vacio o esta llegando un array